# Flutter - make computing time from reload/computing beautiful - not with black screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-state

I am running flutter on windows. I made a Gantt Chart with the flutter rendering library. The refresh for the Gantt Chart is happening via Timer and then Flutter is fetching Data from a Redis Server, when there is a change.
The ugly thing about my program is: Due to high computing for rendering the Gantt chart, I get when a refresh happens, a black screen for approx. 0,5 sec.
Is there any solution to freeze the screen instead of showing the user a black screen?

Here is a short overview from my code:

```
class Gantt extends MultiChildRenderObjectWidget {
  Gantt({
    Key? key,
    //rest of var
    required List<AppointmentItemWrapper> items,
  }), super(key: key, children: items);

class RenderGantt extends RenderBox
    with
        ContainerRenderObjectMixin<RenderBox, DynamicTimelineParentData>,
        RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin<RenderBox, DynamicTimelineParentData> {
  RenderGantt({
  //rest of var
  })

class TimelineItem extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  TimelineItem({
    Key? key,
   //rest of var
  })  :
        super(
        key: key,
        child: child,
      );

class RenderTimelineItem extends RenderProxyBox
    implements MouseTrackerAnnotation {
  RenderTimelineItem({
  //rest of var
  }) 

class AppointmentItemWrapper extends StatefulWidget {}
```

`Gantt` is placed in a `stateful widget`, with `setState((){})` I am changing the items list in the `Gantt` widget.
Due to that, the repaint is triggered and the necessary recalculation of positions, sizes is started and then with `.markNeedsLayout()` and `.markNeedsPaint()` the view is updated.